# Finding inverse of a function that is mixture of exponentials

Tags: inverse, maple

How can we find the inverse of this function?
$$y=\exp(ax)+\exp(bx),$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants

Comment: Why did you use maple tag?

Comment: Another useful link http://math.stackexchange.com/q/23705/8581.

Answer (score 3):

In general, there is no closed form for it. For example, if $a=5$, $b=1$, write $t=e^x$, then you have $t^5+t-y=0$, and it's well-known you can't solve for $t$ in terms of elementary functions.